# Zapier Polling Trigger not working

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to integrate my web api with Zapier using `Web Builder App`. I followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2gb58ImS4c) on Youtube. Here, I created a trigger for Polling an  API:

Step 1: Created API Key Authentication

Step 2: Defined Trigger and used following URL as `Polling: URL`

http://ec2-52-14-141-201.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/api/v1/unsubscribed/users?api_key=fcf62b9bab564da4f757e81d4c22ce423c5f17579615db23900913a14ff4b1ae

Step 3: Defined Sample Result:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "tony",
    "email": "tony_admin@laravel.com",
    "username": "tony_admin",
    "created_at": "2018-03-05 11:51:55",
    "updated_at": "2018-03-05 11:51:55",
    "role": "USER"
  }
]
```

Step 4: Created Zap in which I selected trigger above created and provided the API Key value for authentication and it succeeded on test.

Step 5: Created Action to store the data retrieved from `Step 4` as a row in Spreadsheet and it succeeded on test.

Step 6: Made it Live

Now what I suppose is Zapier will poll the above URL every 5 minutes, get the data from the URL and put it as row in spreadsheet.

But I could not see Spreadsheet being updated. Please help me identify the issue and resolve it.

Warning on APP I'm receiving:

```
Warnings (Click links for details)

Trigger (list_subscribers):
    trigger URL should probably be https (ZDW006)
Auth (api_key):
    Consider using a direct link to API Key location (ZDW009)
```

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

There's a few things to unpack here:

1. **Your API Key** should almost certainly not be posted publicly.  Invalidate it ASAP and use a new one in Zapier.
2. **Warnings** aren't blocking anything (they're just warnings), but they're worth addressing
   a. Your polling url (`http://ec2-52-...`) uses `http` rather than `https`. We strongly encourage the latter for security reasons.
   b. Since you're using an API key auth method, we encourage you to link to docs to make it clear for end users where their key. If this app is just for you, you can safely ignore this
3. New data isn't showing up in the spreadsheet because it doesn't look like there's any new data. The zap will only trigger on each object once, deduplicated based on `id`. So once the user with `id === 1` (or 3, in your url) has been seen by Zapier, nothing will happen. Try changing that data, then hitting "run now" on the dashboard.

Hope this helps. ​Let me know if you've got any other questions!